# How to connect routers in Aiogram

Tags: python, router, aiogram

I have directory structure:

```
├── src
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── handlers.py
```

I wanted to add router inside admin.py and handlers.py but I have a problem. I initialized router inside handlers.py and admin.py

Then have this code inside main.py

```
import asyncio
import logging

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from aiogram.enums.parse_mode import ParseMode
from aiogram.fsm.storage.memory import MemoryStorage

import config
from admin import router1
from handlers import router2


async def main():
    bot = Bot(token=config.BOT_TOKEN, parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
    dp = Dispatcher(storage=MemoryStorage())
    dp.include_routers(router1, router2)
    await bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True)
    await dp.start_polling(bot, allowed_updates=dp.resolve_used_update_types())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    asyncio.run(main())
```

But when I run code only router inside handlers work.

My admin.py code:

```
from aiogram import F, Router, Bot
from aiogram.types import Message, CallbackQuery
from aiogram.filters import Command
import handlers

import kb
import config
import text

global admin_flag
admin_flag = False
global user_id

router1 = Router()
router1.include_router1(handlers.router1)


@router1.message(Command("admin"))
async def admin_handler(msg: Message):
    global user_id
    user_id = int(msg.from_user.id)
    if user_id in config.admins:
        await msg.answer(text.greet_admin, reply_markup=kb.admin_main_menu_kb)
```

and handlers.py code:

```
from aiogram import Router, F, Bot
from aiogram.types import Message, CallbackQuery
from aiogram.filters import Command

import kb
import config
import text

global user, flag
flag = False

router2 = Router()


@router2.message(Command("start"))
async def start_handler(msg: Message):
    user_id = int(msg.from_user.id)
    if user_id not in config.admins:
        await msg.answer(text.greet, reply_markup=kb.main_menu_kb)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the "include_router" method. Try looking in this direction

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect:
`router1.include_router1(handlers.router1)`

It should be `router.include_router()`

Like this:
`router1.include_router(router2)`

IMPORTANT NOTE:

> Note that you should'nt register any handler or router after you start receiveng of the incoming events. All handlers in routers tree should be registered when you construct the application.

Comment: I changed it like this:


main:

`async def main():
    bot = Bot(token=config.BOT_TOKEN, parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
    dp = Dispatcher(storage=MemoryStorage())
    router1.include_router(router2)
    dp.include_router(router1)
    await bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True)
    await dp.start_polling(bot, allowed_updates=dp.resolve_used_update_types())`

command /admin works but command /start doesn't